# Jenkins send email with part of log line

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

I have SOAPUI project with 10 test cases in Jenkins. I set up Jenkins to send me email with information from console output (log).  I have set up email notification content as HTML (text/html).

I have this log in console output in Jenkins:

```
07:25:05,957 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [Login with username and password]
07:25:05,957 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Clear access token]
07:25:05,957 INFO  [log] Environment URL: url.test.environment
07:25:05,958 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Retrieve accessToken]
07:25:05,959 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check
07:25:05,960 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
07:25:05,960 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /api/v2/path HTTP/1.1
07:25:06,010 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 
07:25:06,011 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
07:25:06,017 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [JsonPath Existence Match] has status VALID
07:25:06,017 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [Valid HTTP Status Codes] has status VALID
07:25:06,017 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [JsonPath Existence Match 1] has status VALID
07:25:06,017 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [JsonPath Existence Match 2] has status VALID
07:25:06,017 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Pass accessToken]
07:25:06,019 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [Login with username and password], time taken: 51ms, status: FINISHED
```

I have set up Jenkins to send email just with this line from log:

```
07:25:06,019 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [Login with username and password], time taken: 51ms, status: FINISHED
```

To that I use this regex to find just that line:

```
<pre>${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="Finished running SoapUI testcase \\[Login with username and password\\]", showTruncatedLines=false}</pre>
```

But  I want to have in email notification just parts of that line, something like this:

```
"Login with username and password: FINISHED"
```

or

```
"Login with username and password: FAILED"
```

Is there any way to send email with just part of that line?

Comment: You could try a replaceAll using ths regex: `".+\\[(Login with username and password)\\].*:\\s*(\\w+)$", "$1: $2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Aaron I found a solution.

Now I use this regex:

```
<b>Login with username and password: </b> <font color="green">${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex=".*Finished running SoapUI testcase \\[Login with username and password\\].*status: FINISHED", showTruncatedLines=false, substText="SUCCESS"}</font>
<font color="red">${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex=".*Finished running SoapUI testcase \\[Login with username and password\\].*status: FAILED", showTruncatedLines=false, substText="FAILED"}</font>
```

E-mail notification now looks like this:

**Login with username and password:** SUCCESS

---

or this:

**Login with username and password:** FAILED

---

"SUCCESS" text has green color and "FAILED" text has red color

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can use a `substText` argument to define a replacement pattern :

```
<pre>${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="Finished running SoapUI testcase \\[Login with username and password\\].*status: ([A-Z]+)", showTruncatedLines=false, substText="Login with username and password : \\1"}</pre>
```

This will match only the lines such as the last one from your sample, select the success/failure status in the first capturing group which will be referred in the replacement pattern.

Comment: a substr doesn't work for me, but thanks to you I found the solution.

Comment: @MarekMasek Glad to hear it !

Comment: The actual parameter name is `substText` --Note: the regex must match outside the capture group also. If you don't specify anything outside the capture group, then only the capture group itself will be replaced.

Comment: @MarkHu thanks for the parameter name, I've fixed it.

Comment: I guess the rest of the comment is addressed to future readers? My regex does match outside of the capturing group at least.